# Get all emojis of Telegram Sticker

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I would like to get **all** emoji of a telegram sticker. I have checked out their [bot api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sticker) but it only gives me the main emoji and ignores the others.

For example for the first sticker of the [Nekonyaaaa stickerpack](https://t.me/addstickers/Nekonyaaaa), which has these ☺ emojis, I get only the  emoji.

Answer (score 0):

use `getStickerSet` function:

```
url: https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getStickerSet?name=Nekonyaaaa
```

Comment: This would not work the [sticker element](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sticker) does only have one main emoji. The others are not available.
I think now that it is simple not possible to get all emojis using the bot api.